# Javascript Instagram API showing answer in browser but not in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

I'm just writing a little Instagram app. In a fact when I try to get response from this url in JS :

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=money&client_id=f40dfb17ddd144598d562a6f58179006
```

but for some reason I dont get an answer and no error at all. If I call the url in my Browser I got a JSON formated answer.

Here my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/XQ28k/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are planning to do a cross domain request, you should try the JSONP variant of the API by adding `&callback=?` to the end of the URL

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=money&client_id=f40dfb17ddd144598d562a6f58179006&callback=?
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a different domain from your current domain (where you make the ajax call).
It will give you cross origin error 
Ajax calls only works on the same domain!

A workaround for this is to call a page in your server that this page will make the remote call to Instagram servers and make an ajax call to this page:
php example - in your server page.php:

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/search?q=money&client_id=f40dfb17ddd144598d562a6f58179006';
$content = file_get_contents($url);

echo($content); //no need to json_encode cause the response returning a json already!
```

and in your client side code just call to page.php (which is in your server - so it's the same domain):

```
 $.getJSON("page.php",function(json){
   alert(json.data);
  });
```